# Unknown Column in "On" Clause

Tags: mysql

I'm working on the following `SELECT` statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.contentid = table3.id AND table2.tmplid = table1.id
WHERE table2.value = "test"
```

I'm getting the following error:

> Execution of a query to the database failed - Unknown column
>   'table3.id' in 'on clause' »

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the definition of table3? Have you triple checked it have an `id` column?

Comment: You don't have a `table3` table in your statements, that's what's wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your problem:

```
LEFT JOIN table2 ON table2.contentid = table3.id
```

You can't have any table in your ON clause that's not part of the join (in this case, table3).

Did you mean this instead:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
       LEFT JOIN table2
              ON table1.id = table2.tmplid
       LEFT JOIN table3
              ON table2.contentid = table3.id
WHERE  table2.value = "test"
```

Answer (score 0):

You are referenceing `table3.id` which is not defined in your sql anywhere.  Did you mean to put `table1.id`?

If you want to reference table3 you will need to join on it:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1
LEFT JOIN table3
ON table1.id = table3.someid
LEFT JOIN table2 
ON table2.contentid = table3.id AND table2.tmplid = table1.id
WHERE table2.value = "test"
```